# How the following recursion outputs 48?

Tags: c, recursion, output

How the following recursion in C outputs 48 ?
I expected the output to be 0.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fun(int i) {
   if(i<2)
      return 1;
   else {
      return fun(--i) * i * fun(--i);
   }   
}

int main() {
   printf("%d",fun(5));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Print `i` in `fun()` and see what's occurring ...

Comment: @Alex K. when i put i at the end in the last line of the recursion i.e               {return fun(--i)* fun(--i) * i;} the output is 0.

Comment: Writing too much code on one line will often cause problems because you get illegible code. I bet if you wrote this more clearly, the problems would be come more apparent.

Comment: I already posted the duplicate link, but to sum up your problem: it's not specified which order `fun(--i)`,  `i` , and `fun(--i)` are evaluated in. You don't know if `--i` is going to be evaluated before or after `i` is evaluated.

Comment: if i is evaluated after both the decrement operators then the result is 0

Comment: No, to me, this is happening for another reason. Marking it for reopening (I have an answer)

Comment: It still outputs 48 without the `--i` UB: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7540075283c56c21

Comment: Yes that's why I'd like this question to reopen

Comment: I agree: modify the question to remove the UB. I'm voting to reopen because the duplicate I linked to is about C++, whereas this is a C question (dumb mistake on my part).

Comment: @RajeshSethi I reverted your edit as it will **not** execute the same things (because order matters here) as in the previous version

Comment: @aduch: The order of evaluation of `i`, `--i` and `--i` is undefined in that expression. The order that they are written in __doesn't matter__.

Comment: This is still undefined behavior. It should be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior

Answer (score 2):

The expression `fun(--i) * i * fun(--i)` exhibits undefined behavior. So we can't make any assumptions about what that would produce. If you are curious why it is undefined, then please read: [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

We can attempt to remove the undefined behavior, and talk about that though:

```
int fun(int i) {
   if(i<2)
      return 1;
   else {
      return fun(i - 1) * (i - 1) * fun(i - 2);
   }   
}
```

`fun(5)` should and does produce 48 with the corrected code. And if we need to prove that...

```
fun(0) == 1
fun(1) == 1
fun(2) == fun(1) * 1 * fun(0) == 1 * 1 * 1 == 1
fun(3) == fun(2) * 2 * fun(1) == 1 * 2 * 1 == 2
fun(4) == fun(3) * 3 * fun(2) == 2 * 3 * 1 == 6
fun(5) == fun(4) * 4 * fun(3) == 6 * 4 * 2 == 48
```